# When running 'ionic build ios' on macOS with node 7 I get stuck on this message: stdout maxBuffer exceeded. How could I solve it?

Tags: ios, macos, ionic2

Suddenly I started having this problem when trying to build my iOS app with `ionic build ios` . I don't understand what could be causing it, because it was running just fine, then in the next day I get this message:

```
...
...
Running command: HC-Ionic/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js HC-Ionic

Running command: HC-Ionic/hooks/after_prepare/020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js HC-Ionic


stdout maxBuffer exceeded
```

The only thing I remember doing before this problem started happening was changing my node version sometimes using the application 'n'. But I already uninstalled the versions, set up the right one, but still was not able to figure out, trying to search on the internet.

This is my system info:

```
Cordova CLI: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS
Node Version: v7.10.1
Xcode version: Xcode 12.4 Build version 12D4e
```

This configuration is necessary because my app only runs with this node version.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Node v7.10.1 was [EOL'd in 2017](https://github.com/nodejs/Release) (nearly 4 years ago) - why are you still using it when it's been unsupported for quite some time now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently I had too many simulators on xcode and this exceeded the json in the build. If the list exceeds 200kb, node 7 doesn't compile. Just removed some unnecessary simulators and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Node versions prior to `v 12.x` use a default `maxBuffer` value of 1 kilobyte ([source](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v7.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)), which is realtively small.

Later releases increased the default `maxBuffer` to 1 megabyte ([source](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)) - you should really consider upgrading as the release of Node you're running is ancient (EOL'd in 2017), at least by software standards.